# How to rerender some components but not all?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, state-management

I have an object coming from redux with a photo that I render in a react native class component.

Each time I update the state of the related class component for a different object, the image of the object coming from redux is reloading.

How could I avoid that?

I thought using redux would avoid to re render the object on state update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the state of the component changes the component is re-rendered that is the basic ideology of react-native. You can put conditions in `shouldComponentUpdate()` to limit the number of times the component needs to re-render. This function allows you to conditionally re-render the component instead of re-rendering everytime when the state changes.

Here is the reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

For re-rendering a single element in a component you can use keys that should be unique for every sibling element in a component. React recognizes using these keys that which elements is changed and needs to be re-rendered instead of re-rendering the whole component.

Here is the reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: What would be the statement inside shouldComponentUpdate()? Is it a Boolean ? And does it applies to the children component as well?

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` provides you with the nextProps and ownProps. Which you can use to compare your condition for re-rendering. You need to return true whenever you want to re-render your component or false when you don't want to. By default this function always return true.

Comment: Got it. What about if I want to re render a specific part of the component but not the photo of this component? When you like a post for instance?

Comment: you should use keys to uniquely identify the elements that are changed ..here you go https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Actually, the issue was coming from the key. I was using a random key. I changed and using the stable id of each object coming from my database and now I'm able to update the state and the component without reloading the whole thing. Should I let you update your answer so I can validate it?

Comment: @ShivanshSinghone correction (probably a typo from you).. shouldComponentUpdate provides nextProps and nextState, and not ownProps. ownProps is available via this.props.

Comment: Yes you are write nextProps and nextState not ownProps. Sorry for the mistake.